# declare cuda __constant__ memory in a class

Tags: c++, cuda

I am new to CUDA programming. Currently, I am trying to construct an OO-framework that uses CUDA to parallel process the data. I am currently using CUDA 8.0.

There are some key parameters `__constant__ int foo[3]` that require frequent access by all of the threads, and I think putting them into the constant memory can help improve the memory read process. I would like to have a  declared in the class header and later initializing using `cudaMemcpyToSymbol`.

From other examples (which is not in the OO-context) I understand that the constant memory symbol can be defined as if it is a global variable and initialized using `cudaMemcpyToSymbol`. However, if I define the constant memory symbol in the header of the class, the compiler complains by :

```
error : attribute "__constant__" does not apply here
```

I cannot specify the `__constant__` anywhere within the class definition either. It looks like it is unable to define constant memory in the context of object-orientated framework? Please help if there are any workaround. Thank you very much!

---

myClass.cuh

```
class myClass
{
private:
    __constant__ int foo[3];
    void initialize();
    void compute(); // required repeated and heavy access of foo from every thread
}
```

myClass.cu

```
void myClass::initialize()
{
    int bar[3] ={1,2,3};
    //attempt to copy the data in bar to foo
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(foo, bar, 3*sizeof(int), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CUDA object model doesn't allow memory specifiers (`__constant__`, `__shared__`, `__global__`) within structures or classes. That is a deliberate and sensible design choice -- it means that any compliant object can be instantiated within any memory space, and any compliant object can be copied between memory spaces.

So you can't do what you have described. If you want a small array stored in constant memory, then you have to statically compile it at the compilation unit which you need to access it, or you need to use separate compilation and linking, with the array declared *once* within the linkage. If you want or need more control of scope, then use a namespace. That is as much as can be done.

If, on the other hand, your final intention is to pass this structure to a CUDA kernel by value, then you don't need to worry about constant memory. This is because all kernel arguments as passed in dedicated constant memory on currently supported architectures, and you will get the effect you want without doing anything.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Referring to the last paragraph, do you mean that I can just declare my kernel as `__global__ void compute(int foo[3]);`? and just pass in the variable `foo` by value (and not via a pointer)?

Comment: Yes that is the way it works. There is a limit as to the maximum size of the argument list in bytes (2kb IIRC), but if you can live with that, pass by value as an argument will automagically get you cached constant memory access.